# Multicatch as a new tag

Tags: discussion, tags

A long time ago, I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470428/catch-multiple-exceptions-in-one-line-except-block). Recently (in the past couple of months), I came to realize that it was referring to a principle called multi-catch, which allows the programmer to catch several exception types in one exception block.

Therefore, I re-tagged the question with multi-catch, thereby creating it. Soon after, that new tag was deleted and my question was untagged.

I thought that the multi-catch tag was useful as it does in fact cover a new programming principle, which could possibly (though not necessarily) be interpreted as a synonym of [exception-handling](/questions/tagged/exception-handling).

However, what I see is that the tag has been completely removed, which I feel is wrong.

Would anyone be able to clarify if this is a useful tag and why it may have been removed?

Thank you

Comment: Leeloo Dallas mul-ti-pass.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eV_eGm1qgGs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multicatch strikes me as a "boutique" word, a word coined to describe an obscure concept, familiar only to its insiders. Similar to [fluent-interface](/questions/tagged/fluent-interface), except that term has achieved well-known status.

The term "multicatch" is not used in the Python documentation.

"Performant" is an even better example; it's not a real word, although most programmers know it, and there are zero questions tagged with it.

In short, the tagging system is not there to create "folders" for each individual user.  Tags must be genuinely useful to the community at large.

Comment: I am just playing devil's advocate here, but I will point out that Java 7 now has "multicatch" (although obviously the term isn't part of the official documentation.) The new appearance of this feature in an established language means that more people will be exposed to this concept, so maybe the tag will become useful in the future...